# Adding Semicolon in array of booksName after each BookName , How to change the last semicolon to (And)

Tags: go

I need and example for adding (semicolon) after each bookName in array of bookName , and change the last semicolon to (and) ,
What i have is {"me befor you","fallen","inferno"}
what i need as a result is (me befor you , fallen and inferno)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Something like this is extremely trivial to do, just look at the introduction to slices, and check out `strings.Split`, you should be able to work it out yourself

Comment: actualy yes , and i made an implode function to do that , but it adds , after every tag and i want to change the , before the last tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so this is really quite a simple thing to do (As I said in the comments):

```
books := []string{"title 1", "title 2", "title 3"}
list := fmt.Sprintf(
    "%s and %s",
    strings.Join(books[:len(books)-1], ", "), // join all elements with , excluding last one|
    books[len(books)-1], // last element in slice
)
```

## [Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/gFhw3h_ZbzL)

How it works:

- `strings.Join` is part of the standard package `strings`, which does what your home-grown `impode` function does. No need to write it yourself
- `books[:len(books)-1]` *"creates"* a new slice containing all elements in the original slice, excluding the last one. Joining these elements with comma's is what you want. You just want an `and` bit between this and the last element in the slice.
- `books[len(books)-1]` gets the last element in the slice
- `fmt.Sprintf("%s and %s"`: this creates a string where the first part is the comma separated list created by `strings.Join`, and the second part is the last element in the slice.

Together this yields `"title 1, title 2 and title 3"`